# Dynamic Variable inside Oozie EL Function

Tags: hadoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am writing a frequency-based coordinator workflow.
The configs are stored in some oozie.wf.properties file as:

```
-- java properties config
myFrequencyDays=1
```

The coordinator definition looks like:

```
<coordinator-app xmlns="uri:oozie:coordinator:0.4" name="MyCoord"  frequency="${coord:days($myFrequencyDays)}" start="${coordStartTime}" end="${coordEndTime}" timezone="${timezone}">  
   <action>
      <workflow>
         <app-path>${appLocation}/application.workflow.xml</app-path>
      </workflow>
   </action>
</coordinator-app>
```

This however fails with EL Parsing error because of `${coord:days($myFrequencyDays)}`
Any idea to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use a parameter from properties inside of an Oozie EL function. The solution would be to use the [chron syntax](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a4.4.3._Cron_syntax_in_coordinator_frequency) described in the Coordinator Functional Spec.

So, in your properties file you would have something like `frequency="0 12 * * *"` and the coordinator definition would include `frequency=${frequency}`